# Read file line by line, then convert strings to two-dimensional integer array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to read information from a text file a single line at a time. Consider the following example file:

```
Student 1, 45, 32, 45
Student 2, 34, 22, 23
```

I then want to store the data in a string array, and then convert the string arrays into a two-dimensional integer array because I need to be able to manipulate their scores. Unfortunately, the number of students is unknown

I decided to create a for loop that reads the data line by line, stores it in my string array, and then finally converts it into a two-dimensional integer array.

My code isn't quite working as expected.

```
int [][]score = null;
String [][]studentDataParsed = null;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
        String oneStudentData = input.nextLine(); //read one line from input file
        oneStudentData.split("[,]"); //parse the data
        studentDataParsed[i][j] = oneStudentData; 
        //convert the data into the double array                
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < studentDataParsed.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; i < studentDataParsed.length; ++j) {
        score[i][j]=(int) (Float.valueOf(studentDataParsed[i [j])).floatValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're up to with the loops. You should already be using a loop to read lines, so you just need to track lines and assign the split string to your array:

```
int curline = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       studentDataParsed[curline] = line.split(",");
       curline++;
    }
}
```

You might also consider creating a Student class, reading each line into the constructor of that class, and using a List to store the results.